# work space specific variable to use in power bi query dynamically

Tags: parameters, powerbi, azure-application-insights

Use Case: 
We are getting app insight custom event data from app insight and publishing it in power bi using power bi queries. We have 3 environments (Dev,PreProd and Prod). We have created 3 work spaces for each environments.

Question:
The queries use application insight App ID which is hardcoded for now. Is there a way to pass the App ID dynamically since it will be different for different workspace/environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use is parameters. Guy in a Cube [did a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlUfz18cx_w) about something similar awhile back, but the process can be modified to work with App Insights.

The instructions for creating a connection to App Insights from Power BI Desktop ask you to export the M code from App Insights and then copy it into a blank query. Go ahead and open up the query editor, but instead of copying in the code right away, first make a parameter to hold the link to the specific App Insights instance you want to connect to.

[image]

[image]

Once you have the parameter created, you can open up the query's advanced editor and paste in the code you exported from App Insights. Replace the connection string with the parameter you created.

[image]

Complete the rest of the work on the report, and publish it to the service. Finally, go into each workspace and update the parameter in the dataset's settings menu.

[image]

Currently parameters do get overwritten when you publish changes. However, if you use a script to push the updates to the separate workspaces you can also use that script to set the parameter in each.

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Could you please share a link or give some more detail on using script to push the updates to separate workspaces ?

Comment: You can do this with the Rest API and the language of your choice: (clone to new workspace) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/clonereportingroup, (update parameters) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparametersingroup

Comment: It is worth noting that the REST API endpoint for updating the parameters requires to be the Owner of the dataset, which is a strong limitation in a multi-user scenario. Whereas the update of PBIX report/dataset is permitted to a larger set of user, only the owner is allowed to update the parameters...