# Script to publish power bi reports

Tags: powerbi

According to the below mentioned post we can use script to publish power bi report changes to separate workspaces and we will be able to set different parameter values to each of them.
[work space specific variable to use in power bi query dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376813/work-space-specific-variable-to-use-in-power-bi-query-dynamically/56398364#56398364)

I am very new to this.Could you please help me with the script to achieve the above mentioned use case ? If there is any link or blog or document on this ,please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Power BI Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps) and write a PowerShell script, which you can run after publishing updates to your report. Invoke update and refresh commands for each of the datasets (in each of the workspaces). Replace `{group id}`, `{gataset id}`, `{Parameter name}` and `{Parameter value}` with actual values.

```
# Install Power BI Cmdlets
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -Scope CurrentUser

# Login
Login-PowerBI

# Update parameter's value
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/{group id}/datasets/{dataset id}/UpdateParameters' -Method Post -Body '{
  "updateDetails": [
    {
      "name": "{Parameter name}",
      "newValue": "{Parameter value}"
    }
  ]
}'

# Refresh the dataset, in case the data is imported
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/{group id}/datasets/{dataset id}/refreshes' -Method Post
```